# jquery get class name from "this" of an element

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

please tell me how can i get the class name from "this" in an each loop in jquery.
I need it because I want to use the class name to select another class name within the first

here's the code. I'ts giving me an error

```
$("#WebPartWPQ3 .ms-itmhover").each(function(){   $(this.attr('class')+" td").css("background","black")   });
```

Comment: _I want to use the class name to select another class name within the first_......shed some more light on it, although you got many answers for your post.

Comment: well the thing is i wanted to actually iterate through all the table rows and extract individual values from the table cells of a particular row. That line was just for testing if I'm getting the right column. Any way i figured that it's better to actually first assign a unique id to each table row and then access it's nested elements.

Comment: Sharepoint is a web - developer's nightmare hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

You have Typo

```
$(this.attr('class')+" td")
 //  ^ need to close $(this) and than have to use .find()
```

---

```
$("#WebPartWPQ3 .ms-itmhover").each(function(){   
    $(this).find("td").css("background","black");
});
```

---

Or

```
$("#WebPartWPQ3 .ms-itmhover").each(function(){
    var cls = $(this).attr('class').split(' ').join('.');
    $('.'+ cls +" td").css("background","black")   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)** instead:

```
$("#WebPartWPQ3 .ms-itmhover").each(function(){   
    $(this).find("td").css("background","black")   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
$(this).attr('class');
```

but a cleaner way to do this would be:

```
 $(this).find("td").css("background","black");
```

complete code:

```
$("#WebPartWPQ3 .ms-itmhover").each(function(){   
  $(this).find("td").css("background","black");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `this.className` to get the class name:

```
$("#WebPartWPQ3 .ms-itmhover").each(function(){   
    $('.'+this.className+" td").css("background","black"); 
});
```

but instead i recommend to you to go within context of your selectors loop:

```
$(this).find("td").css("background","black");
```

or

```
$("td", this).css("background","black");
```